# SYSPREP Windows 7 After language bar install

Tags: windows-7, sysprep, language, windows

I had a sysprep file that worked fine with windows 7 ent. However I installed chinese simplified and now after the sysprep runs it comes up with a box to choose english or chinese.
I have it set to use en-au for input lang.
Is there somewhere else I have to change or add somthing new?
thanks

Also I keep getting prompted for which type of network this is which is also set in the answer file.
See below for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipRearm>8</SkipRearm>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpSysprep" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <PersistAllDeviceInstalls>true</PersistAllDeviceInstalls>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ComputerName>*</ComputerName>
            <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>
            <TimeZone>E. Australia Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Identification>
                <Credentials>
                    <Domain>XXXXXX</Domain>
                    <Password>XXXXXX</Password>
                    <Username>XXXXXX</Username>
                </Credentials>
                <JoinDomain>XXXXXX</JoinDomain>
            </Identification>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>JAAyADAAMAA4AGwAYwBBAGQAbQBpAG4AaQBzAHQAcgBhAHQAbwByAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>XXXXXXA</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Name>XXXXXX</Name>
                        <Group>administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName>Desktopadmin</DisplayName>
                        <Description>Local Admin Account</Description>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <RegisteredOrganization>XXXXX</RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>XXXXXX</RegisteredOwner>
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>XXXXXX</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Domain>slc</Domain>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
                <Username>XXXXXX</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-us</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-au</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-au</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-us</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-au</UserLocale>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>English</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="catalog:g:/applications/windows 7 deployment tools/win 7 ent/sources/install_windows 7 enterprise.clg" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i ended up doing is taking all the language packs available from windows updates or i found a list here http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/07/26/download-windows-7-rtm-32-bit-x86-and-64-bit-x64-mui-language-packs-gold-msdntechnet-iso/

I have taken the lp.cab files made when you run each language setup exe, renamed each one and then after the machine has installed after sysprep I run the lpksetup.exe /i * c:\langpackspath which installs the languages.  the only thing I think required after that is to add the HKCU\Keyboard layout reg keys for the language bar.

Comment: OK Thanks I will try this. I got the resource kit just havent had a chance to read the beast yet. There should be an easier way than this you would hope though